# C# find if dns is exist on dns server (from Domain controller)

Tags: c#, dns

i want to check if dns record is exist on my domain controller.
example:
if i want ro check i i have the host "guest_PC" on the dns server on my Work domain.

Comment: Then do a dns lookup, whats the question and problems you are having with it

Comment: that i need to query a specific dns server..

Comment: So you didnt search stack overflow then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227863/dns-lookup-from-custom-dns-server-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DNS lookup from custom DNS server in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227863/dns-lookup-from-custom-dns-server-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You can use libraries, like [DnsClient.NET](http://dnsclient.michaco.net) https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET and run any queries you want.

Answer (score 2):

The following example queries the DNS database for information on the host www.contoso.com.

```
    using System.Net;
    IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName("www.contoso.com");
    static string IP = Dns.GetHostName();
```

Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use libraries like [DnsClient.NET](http://dnsclient.michaco.net) (https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET) to run queries against any DNS server from within your code/app.

Here is just a quick example of how to use the library:

```
// use the IP Address of your DNS server
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"), 53);
var client = new LookupClient(endpoint);

// then query for the host in your domain and ask for an A or AAAA record
var result = client.Query("YouHost.yourdomain", QueryType.A);
var ipRecord = result.Answers.ARecords().First();
Console.WriteLine($"IP: {ipRecord.Address}.");

// shortcut
var entry = client.GetHostEntry("YourHost.yourdomain");
Console.WriteLine($"IP: {entry.AddressList.First()} hostName: {entry.HostName}");
```