# Test that computer has functioning dns server via c#

Tags: c#, dns

How to test that a specified computer is a functioning DNS server via c#? Something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/test-dnsserver?view=windowsserver2019-ps but via c# code

Comment: Would it be enough to just execute that PS function via c#?

Comment: No, I want to do it without executing powershell from c# code

Comment: possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258203/c-sharp-find-if-dns-is-exist-on-dns-server-from-domain-controller

Comment: This should be a good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267003/4800344

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.